# divs inside divs positioning - no div fixed height

Tags: html, css

I know this is probably really simple, but i'm stuck on it for a while trying fiddle around with it.

Basically, this is my html setup :

```
<div id="main-div"><!-- Blue -->
     <div id="sub-div"><!-- Red -->
       <div class="content-div">
        <p>This is the text. I need the button to be placed in content-div, which technically is, but it appers outside the div.</p>
        <a href="#" class="button-green">BUTTON</a>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
```

Here is the fiddle with the CSS classes :
http://jsfiddle.net/03knuf7z/1/

What I'm trying to achieve is to have the `<p> paragraph` and `<a> button` both inside the `sub-div` surrounded by `main-div`

I've been trying to achieve this without a fixed `content-div` height, so I'm trying to put in `height: auto;` into my css hoping the `content-div` will stretch enough to cover both `<p>` and `<a>` elements, but that doesn't do the job, because the button still appears outside the `content-div` box, just like in the fiddle.

I can achieve the desired result by putting fixed height to the `content-div`, so if I'll change the `auto` in `height: auto;` to `height: 150px;`, it works and both elements, the paragraph and the button are in the box.

But thinking of responsivity on small screen devices, phone screens for example, I'd like to avoid fixed values.

Is there a way to do this without fixed height ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an element with [`clear`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear) after the button with `float`.
You can add this to the HTML, or use the CSS [`:after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3A%3Aafter) pseudo-element to create a virtual element at the end of your `content-div`:

```
.content-div:after {
    content:'';
    clear:both;
    display:block;
}
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/03knuf7z/5/)

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much, works great !! I can't vote up your answer due to my insufficient reputation unfortunately, but thanks so much for your help. It has been quite frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

This can be fixed easily with a clear class. I have updated your [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/03knuf7z/4/).

I have added the following class:

```
.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

And this  after your button:

```
<div class="clear"></div>
```

You can also use the `:after` property. Then you will have the use the following CSS:

```
.content-div:after {
    display: block;
    content: " ";
    clear: both;
    height: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thomas many thanks, I can't vote up your answer due to my insufficient reputation unfortunately, but really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow-hidden;` to `.content-div`.

```
.content-div{
  font-size: 18px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```